# How to add custom sort order in sql query?

Tags: mysql, search

I have a a table with some tag names and there expertise area like below

```
TID  TAGS
1    Cars
2    Luxury Cars
3    4 wheel drive cars
```

and i have a query like

```
select * from tablename where tags like '%Cars%' OR like '%Luxury%';
```

Now i getting the result, but i would like to show the tags that has maximum keywords in first row.

for eg: if i passed Luxury and Cars then i would like to get the result as below.

```
Luxury Cars
Cars
4 wheel drive cars
```

I hope you understand what i mean?

one more thing, i would like to know is there any other nice way to do this.
i want a search functionality like google.

Comment: "i want a search functionality like google." - good luck with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using an expression in the `order by` clause.

```
select *
from tablename
where tags like '%Cars%' OR like '%Luxury%'
order by (tags like '%Cars%') + (tags like '%Luxury%') desc;
```

MySQL treats booleans results as numbers.  So adding them together gives the number of matches.